# javascript void links with RSpec

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, void, nav

My Rails app uses nav pills to change the partial used on a form.

```
%ul.nav.nav-pills
   %li.active
      %a{href: "javascript:void()", id: 'post_one_partial', name: 'post_one_tab'} Post One
    %li
      %a{href: "javascript:void()", id: 'post_many_partial', name: 'post_many_tab'} Post Many
```

These work well in development mode, using this coffeescript.

```
$(document).on 'click', '#post_one_partial, #post_many_partial', ->
  post_id = $(this).attr('id')
  $('#'+post_id).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
  if post_id == 'post_one_partial'
    $('#many_form').hide()
    $('#form').show()
  else
    $('#form').hide()
    $('#many_form').show()
  false
```

The goal here is to keep two ways of creating records contained within a single `create` action, rather than splitting it up. When I click on the nav pills in development, all is well, but attempting to simulate the process in testing with RSpec doesn't. As it progresses through my commands, it "clicks" the button (or so I believe, because `javascript:void()` appears in the bottom left corner of the browser window), but nothing happens. There are no changes made to the form at all. Is there another setting of some sort that I'm missing?

**Feature spec**

```
scenario "User posts many trucks", js: true do
  ResqueSpec.reset!

  visit "/trucks/new"
  click_on "post_many_partial"
  page.should have_content "Enter the number of trucks to post."
  fill_in "post_many_trucks", with: 3
  click_on "Submit"
  # further code tests after form is updated
end
```

This spec is currently failing when clicking `post_many_partial`. When the link "is clicked", I see `javascript:void()` on the screen, but the form doesn't update. From that point, the test fails because `post_many_trucks` doesn't exist on the page yet.

Comment: Will you post your test that you are trying to pass?